# PyQt4 ImportError for QtWebKit‏ on Mac OS Leopard

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, osx-leopard, qtwebkit

I've been requested to create an application with a webview in it.
I've tried to import QtWebKit module but I have this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/QtWebKit.so, 2): Symbol
>   not found: _kCFWebServicesProviderDefaultDisplayNameKey   Referenced
>   from: /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation

It's the only one module that returns this error. All other installed modules are ok. The file /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/QtWebKit.so exists.
What could the problem be?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by upgrading to MacOSX Lion, but if that is not an option I would just ensure that PyQt4 is *not* using qt4.8, which is where this issue was introduced. If I remember correctly, everything works well with qt4.7.4

Comment: thank you very much. I've temporarly given up that project, but I'll try your solution in the future.